# CGContext - PDF margin

Tags: iphone

I am showing PDF content on a view using this code using Quartz Sample:

```
 // PDF page drawing expects a Lower-Left coordinate system, so we flip the coordinate system
 // before we start drawing.
 CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, self.bounds.size.height);
 CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

 // Grab the first PDF page
 CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, pageNo);
 // We're about to modify the context CTM to draw the PDF page where we want it, so save the graphics state in case we want to do more drawing
 CGContextSaveGState(context);
 // CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform provides an easy way to get the transform for a PDF page. It will scale down to fit, including any
 // base rotations necessary to display the PDF page correctly. 
 CGAffineTransform pdfTransform = CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(page, kCGPDFCropBox, self.bounds, 0, true);
 // And apply the transform.
 CGContextConcatCTM(context, pdfTransform);
 // Finally, we draw the page and restore the graphics state for further manipulations!
 CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, page);
 CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

Using this all works fine.  I want to set the margin for the PDF context, by default it showing 50 px margin in every side.  I have tried CGContext methods but not got the appropriate one. Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

PDFs don't really have any concept of margins. If you're not the one responsible for the document's content then all you can really do is scale it down.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer for this here

[CGContext pdf page aspect fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908624/cgcontext-pdf-page-aspect-fit)